# How To Inverse Search From Internal PDF Viewer To The Actual Code in VS Code for a Latex Doument

Tags: visual-studio-code, latex, tex, synctex

I am using VS Code and in it, I am using LaTeX Workshop by James Yu. I am trying to compile my document using LaTeX Workshop. When I compile my code to a pdf file, I can double click or ctrl + click on a word in the pdf to go to that line of code which produced that output. But, when it comes to doing the opposite, that is going from the line of code to that specific line in the PDF, I am unable to do so. I have scanned all the settings available to me and I can't figure out what to do. I am using the internal pdf viewer and everything is working fine for me.

I did google the problem and there are solutions available for external pdf viewers but nothing for internal pdf viewer. I don't want to switch to any external pdf viewer since everything is working fine for me till now in the internal pdf viewer.

So, it would be really helpful if someone pointed out to me what I am missing. Essentially, I want to double click or ctrl click on a word in my tex code and be taken to that word in the pdf if that's possible or at least in the range of that word in the pdf.

I am fairly new to LaTex. So, this is my first long document. Trying to figure out stuff as I do.

[image]

Thank you in advance for helping.

Comment: I know that the feature exists, that was not the question. Part of the feature is not working and that is why I asked the question!

Comment: I tried this. The problem is still there. I can click on the pdf and get to the line of code which produced that output but the reverse is not working. 

I also tried sumatra pdf but In fact, it faired worst then the internal pdf viewer.  

In my main document, I have included chapters because I am trying to compile a fairly long document. The internal pdf viewer takes me to the line of code inside of the included chapter but the external pdf viewer only takes me to the main.tex file on the line where it is written \include{Some Chapter} which in essence is pretty useless.

Comment: I am not using sub-directories for each individual chapters. I have a main folder in which the main file is stored. All the chapters are stored in a sub-folder named 'chapters' in the main folder. There is no more folders inside the chapter folder, so no individual folder for each chapter. 

Since, This is a book I am trying to compile, I find it hard not to at least have some structure in the folder. It would become a disaster pretty soon if I just keep everything in one folder.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help.

Really appreciate it.

Comment: I am very new at this so I am not sure what to make of all this. But my experince has mostly been very good with vs code and its internal pdf viewer. I could not edit anything in notepad even if I tried. I don't know how you do it. It just makes this look so bizzare for me. In my limited experience, I have always used IDEs so I guess I am pretty used to them. 

Thanks for all the help once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

**To go from editor to internal pdf viewer's pdf:**

> `Ctrl + Alt + J`

**To go from internal pdf viewer's pdf to editor:**

> `Double Click or Ctrl + Click`

You can choose one at the settings here in vs code:

```
latex-workshop.view.pdf.internal.synctex.keybinding
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you very much. I could not find the 'Ctrl + Alt + J' shortcut in the settings and I don't think I can change it, right?

I can definitely choose between the double click or ctrl + click. I had already found that settngs but not the other one, so thank you!

Comment: @AaronJones

Of course you can change that. Go to VS Code keybinding settings and change it to whatever you want it to be. That will do it.

Cheers!